# Pulling a variable into the wp_nav_menu function

Tags: php, functions, menus, variables

I looked around and couldn't get any answer that helped me.

I have an include that I am calling in multiple headers (I have different headers for different sections of a membership site that need different menus and resources.)

**template-main-nav.php:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="close-menu"></div>
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu'              => $menu_name,
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 1,
        'menu_class'        => 'main-menu',
        'menu_id'           => 'main-menu'
    )
); ?>
    <div class="header-tools">
        <div class="icon-list">
            <a href="/help" class="icon help trigger-help" title="help"></a>
            <a href="/dashboard" class="icon account" title="my account"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and above the header in each header-x.php file I am declaring the $menu_name variable:

```
<?php
    $menu_name = 'Section 1 Menu';
    get_template_part('template-main-nav');
?>
```

I want multiple different menus I've created in the admin to go into the same location and this seemed like the best solution. The thing is I can't get the variable to pass, no matter how I format it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your scope is not the same. You are defining the `$menu_name` in one scope and calling it in another scope. So you can do it with `global` variable like below-

```
$GLOBALS[ 'menu_name' ] = 'Section 1 Menu';
```

And call it like-

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="close-menu"></div>
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu'              => $GLOBALS[ 'menu_name' ],
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 1,
        'menu_class'        => 'main-menu',
        'menu_id'           => 'main-menu'
    )
); ?>
    <div class="header-tools">
        <div class="icon-list">
            <a href="/help" class="icon help trigger-help" title="help"></a>
            <a href="/dashboard" class="icon account" title="my account"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.